# marging case statement in salesforce with and statement

Tags: salesforce

Please help me to answer this question:

I created a new Formula field called "Car Rating" that will be calculated as follows:

1) In case "Color" field equals "Red" and "Category" field equals "mini", Car Rating value should be 1.

2). In case "Color" field equals “Blue" and "Category" field equals "manager", Car Rating value should be 2.

3). In case "Color" field equals "Yellow" and "Category" field equals "premium", Car Rating value should be 3.

this what I tried to do to answer this question, and it's not working the question if my answer is correct I need your help, please what should I do here

CASE(AND(ISPICKVAL(Color__c, "Red"),( ISPICKVAL( Car_Category__c , "mini")),1 ) CASE(AND(ISPICKVAL(Color__c, "blue"),( ISPICKVAL( Car_Category__c , "manager")),2 ) CASE(AND(ISPICKVAL(Color__c, "Yellow"),( ISPICKVAL( Car_Category__c , "premium")),3,0 )

Thanks, Liraz

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an nested IF statement:

```
    IF ( AND( ISPICKVAL(Color__c, 'Red'), ISPICKVAL(Car_Category__c,'mini'),1,
 IF(AND( ISPICKVAL(Color__c, 'blue'), ISPICKVAL(Car_Category__c,'manager'), 2, 
 IF(AND( ISPICKVAL(Color__c, 'Yellow'), ISPICKVAL(Car_Category__c,'premium'), 3, null) 
) 
)
```

Comment: Are u sure that u put all ')' from my code snippet into your code? Also the last 2

Comment: The "and" are not closed properly. So just add an ")" to each end of the "and"

Comment: can you please write me it, in right way, I am not succeeding with it,